# How to Create Model Container Object

Tags: database, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209121/system-argumentexception-occurred-in-system-data-entity-dll-for-entity-mybase-n) a while back but no one was a able to tackle it. So I did some more testing and determined it is in my code that the problem exists. So my question is, what am I doing wrong?

So I create the model container:

```
Private mdbContext As PFModelContainer
Private mdbTransactions As Object
```

Before I did it this way:

```
Private mdbContext As New PFModelContainer
Private mdbTransactions As mdbContext.Transactions
```

Thinking maybe I was doing something wrong I changed it over to the first way, then I do:

```
Public Sub New()
  mdbContext = New PFModelContainer
  mdbTransactions = mdbContext.Transactions
End Sub
```

Once I hit `mdbContext = New PFModelContainer` it takes me over to the `PFModel.Designer.vb` Where it steps through the following:

```
Public Sub New()
  MyBase.New("name=PFModelContainer", "PFModelContainer")
```

At which point it terminates execution of the code. Am I doing something wrong here?

This is the error it gives me on the Immediate window:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in System.Data.Entity.dll

Is there something I can do to make this error go away? I tried deleting the project and recreating it with my old .edmx model that I downloaded from Mozy from when it used to work. It stopped working (as far as I can tell) after I changed the .edmx model and updated it. Maybe I did something else in the other project too, but I'm not recalling anything.

This is what is in the app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PFModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PFModel.csdl|res://*/PFModel.ssdl|res://*/PFModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\MyDatabase#1.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Should I be referencing `System.Data.EntityClient` and `System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5` somewhere?

The EDMX property `Entity Container Name` is `PFModelContainer` and the `Namespace` is `PFModel`.

Comment: Do you have `PFModelContainer` connection string in your app.config? If you open your EDMX do you see container name set to `PFModelContainer` in properties window?

Comment: I added the answers to your questions to the bottom of my post. Thank you very much for your help! I don't know if there is any way to award you more points but if there is let me know! This has been terribly frustrating. Looking at your profile I don't know if you would even want extra points, but I would gladly give them!

Comment: Figured it out. I put the answer over on the [other post][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209121/system-argumentexception-occurred-in-system-data-entity-dll-for-entity-mybase-n/7409637#7409637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out that I need to update the tt model by right clicking in the edmx model and pressing

> ```
> Add Code Generation Item
> ```

Then

> ```
> ADO.NET DbContext Generator
> ```

I suppose I did it before but I don't remember doing it.